# WebApi controllers inheriting from generic base controller?

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, asp.net-web-api

In my WebApi2 project I use repository and UoW patterns and service pattern. I have over 60 referential entities (eg. customer type, product category, title, country, bankcode, etc...) where the controllers always have same actions (Get, Find, Create, Update, Delete). These controllers will then call the respective service methods.

Some of these controllers might have additional actions depending on their models, but the basic actions are always available and the code is more or less the same.

So, taking as an example the CustomerType entity, I have the following classes:

```
CustomerType
CustomerTypeDto
CustomerTypeRepository : IRepository<CustomerType>
CustomerTypeError (enum)
CustomerTypeService : IEntityService<CustomerType>
CustomerTypeController
```

where:

```
public interface IRepository<T> where T : class
{
    T Get(int id);
    Add(T entity);
    Update(T entity);
    Delete(T Entity);
}

public interface IEntityService<T>
{
    T Get(int id);
    Add(T entity);
    Update(T entity);
    Delete(T Entity);
}
```

A typical controller might look like:

```
public class CustomerTypeController : ApiController
{
    private readonly ICustomerTypeService customerTypeService;

    public CustomerTypeController (ICustomerTypeService customerTypeService)
    {
        this.customerTypeService= customerTypeService;
    }

    public Task<IHttpActionResult> Create(CustomerTypeDto dto)
    {
        try
        {
            var entity = Mapper.Map<CustomerType>(dto);
            entity = customerTypeService.Save(entity);

            return Ok(Mapper.Map<CustomerTypeDto>(entity));
        }
        catch (ValidationException<CustomerTypeErrorEnum> vex)
        { }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return InternalServerError(ex);
        }
    }
}
```

My question is:

Would it make sense to have a base generic controller so that all CRUD code is located there and only overloading methods when necessary?

Would such generic controller have the following signature:

```
public abstract class BaseEntityController<TModel, TDto, TService, TErrorEnum>
{ }
```

Comment: If you're using IoC, why do you want to hardwire dependencies in the controller, instead of injecting them? Yo can do it if you want, but, you must out the focus on thinking if, on a medium or long term, you're going to get into trouble because of this implementation. If not, go on. If yes, don't do it, and inject the dependencies with your IoC containers to keep your architecture much more flexible.

Comment: What would be the benefit of having so many levels of abstraction (controller -> service -> repository -> (probably) ORM context/session? Just call the service dependency directly.

Comment: He might want to go the generic route because a specific controller might need specific calls that all of them do not need or can even support.